# how to change div background image with animation

Tags: html, background, jquery-animate

Is there a way to change `DIV` background with fadeout or animation in JQuery?

For example, I wanna change the background with this code

```
$('#DIV').css("background", "url(Image1.jpg)")

if (Button1 == true) {
$('#DIV').css("background", "url(Image2.jpg)") }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this Jquery :

```
function test() {
    $("#DIV").each(function(index) {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).delay(2000* index).fadeIn(2000).fadeOut();
    });
}
test();
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RyGKV/663/)**

or try this :

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RyGKV/665/)**

```
$('.imges').fadeTo('slow', 0.3, function()
{
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(http://mintywhite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/fond-ecran-wallpaper-image-arriere-plan-hd-29-HD.jpg)');
}).delay(1000).fadeTo('slow', 1);
```

---

regards to your Edit I think this sweets your need :

```
var rotateEvery = 2; //seconds
var images = [
    "http://placehold.it/148x148",
    "http://placehold.it/150x149"];
var curImage = 0;
setInterval(delayFunction, rotateEvery*1000);
function delayFunction() {
  if(curImage == images.length){
    curImage = 0;
  }
  $('#homeback').fadeOut('slow',function(){
    $(this).css("background-image",'url('+images[curImage]+')').fadeIn('slow');
      curImage++;
  });

}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3yN8a/164/)**

Comment: i wanna change for example 'image1.jpg' to 'image2.jpg' as background I think this code can't change it

Comment: I tested your demo but it have 3 different <img> tag that it do change backgrounds together with animation, but I want change <div> background from image1.jpg to imag2.jpg, I want change just one DIV background

Comment: thanks for your update,I tested it in my program, but it haven't good animation effects yet, so if It's possible use different code for better effect so i need it